# Computing the characters of $\prod^t_{i=1} S_{N_i} \wr D_{m_i} $

Tags: representation-theory, symmetric-groups, characters, dihedral-groups, semidirect-product

Let a group be $\prod^t_{i=1} S_{N_i} \wr D_{m_i} $ where $t \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ and } t \ge 1; N_i, m_i \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ and }  N_i, m_i \ge 1$; and $S_{N_i}$ is a symmetric group over $N_i$ symbols and $D_{m_i}$ is the dhedral group of order $2 m_i$.

**My question:**
How do I compute the characters of $\prod^t_{i=1} S_{N_i} \wr D_{m_i} $?

**An example:**
Let $t = 2, N_1 = 3, N_2 = 4, m_1 = 5, \text{ and } m_2 = 6$. So, how do I compute the characters of the following group?

$$
\prod^2_{i=1} S_{N_i} \wr D_{m_i} \\
=  \left(S_{N_1} \wr D_{m_1}\right) \times \left(S_{N_2} \wr D_{m_2}\right)\\
=  \left(S_3 \wr D_5\right) \times \left(S_4 \wr D_6\right)\\
=  \left(\left( S_3 \right)^5 \rtimes D_5\right) \times \left(\left( S_4 \right)^6 \rtimes D_6\right)\\
=  \left(\left( S_3 \times S_3 \times S_3 \times S_3 \times S_3 \right) \rtimes D_5\right) \times \left(\left( S_4 \times S_4 \times S_4 \times S_4 \times S_4 \times S_4 \right) \rtimes D_6\right)
$$

So, how do I compute the characters of $\left(\left( S_3 \times S_3 \times S_3 \times S_3 \times S_3 \right) \rtimes D_5\right) \times \left(\left( S_4 \times S_4 \times S_4 \times S_4 \times S_4 \times S_4 \right) \rtimes D_6\right)$?

Comment: Well firstly characters of direct sums are just product of characters so the problem reduces to individual factors.

Comment: @AsharTafhim, I am comfortable about determining the characters of direct products. But I am not sure how to do it for semidirect products.